# How to migrate the permissions of logins - for example - grant/remove/deny permissions on system objects and server instance?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, migration

I'm migrating sql server 2017 to sql server 2019 on a separate machine.

I have backed up all the user databases, scripted all the sql jobs and logins.

On target server I will 1st run the logins script, then restore the user dbs and then the jobs.

How to migrate the permissions of logins - for example - grant/remove/deny permissions on system objects and server instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Report of permissions in SQL server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266302/report-of-permissions-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Microsoft Migration Assistant to handle this task:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595

I found it quite valuable when moving from 2017 to 2019.

Comment: The DMA tool takes care of schema, data, database users, permissions (grants/removekes/denys) as well as server roles, custom server roles, permissions.

Comment: But I dont think it allows to migrate system object permissions - any idea?

Comment: Not on that, no. It was all user objects. Sorry, hope it helps get you closer to your goal though.

Answer (score 0):

Normally i use this script to have the permissions at instance level:

https://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_srvpermissions/

Comment: Is there nothing from Microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft provides script to transfer logins, Here SID level mapping is done so that user database and its users could get mapped automatically after restoration - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://dbatools.io/?  There are cmdlets that can do the job for you. The logins are grabbed as sql management objects and created on target servers in the exact same way they existed on the source server. The command you are looking for is `Copy-DBALogin`. Check docs here https://docs.dbatools.io/Copy-DbaLogin.
Syntax:

```
Copy-DBALogin -Source $Server1 -Destination $Server2 -Login $Login1 -EnableExecption.
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @mustaccio, I will throw my syntax in code blocks next time!